# Javascript: how to calculate the total

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the total price of a cart. Theoretically, the function should update the total whenever I press the "buy" button, but it just replaces the price.

Instead of doing 0 + price + price + price +..., it does 0 + price, then again 0 + price.

How can I fix it?

```js
function buy(id) {

  var total = 0;
  for (var i in albums) {
    if (albums[i].id == id) {
      if (albums[i].quantity > 0) {
        albums[i].quantity--;
        total += albums[i].price;
      }
    }
  }


  for (var i in singles) {
    if (singles[i].id == id) {
      if (singles[i].quantity > 0) {
        singles[i].quantity--;
        total += singles[i].price;
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i in soundtracks) {
    if (soundtracks[i].id == id) {
      if (soundtracks[i].quantity > 0) {
        soundtracks[i].quantity--;
        total += soundtracks[i].price;
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('purchases').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<button onClick='buy("+this.id+")'>Buy</button>
```

Comment: What is the value of total after you `+= singles[i].price;`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You're declaring `total` *inside* the function, which means it keeps getting deleted whenever the function finishes. Just move `var total = 0;` above the `function`.

Comment: Side note, your for loops are almost identical.  That's a code smell for refactoring into a reusable method, imho.

Comment: why would you give a negative rating to this guy? He is just asking questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the `total` out as others pointed out, but I also made some refactors to remove repeated logic.

```js
//moved the total outside of the method so it is not reinitialized
//as others have already mentioned
var total = 0;

//also reduced your repeated logic
function totalElements (elements, id) {
  elements.forEach(function(element){
    if (element.id == id && element.quantity > 0) {
      element.quantity--;
      total += element.price;
    }
  });
}

function buy(id) {
  totalElements(albums, id);
  totalElements(singles, id);
  totalElements(soundtracks, id);

  document.getElementById('purchases').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<button onClick='buy("+this.id+")'>Buy</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Everytime time you do a button click, you are calling your`buy function`. In that function you are declaring `var total = 0`. Thats why it always starts with 0. You should declare your total not with 0 but with previous number. In your case, that would be from  `document.getElementById('purchases').innerHTML`. So 
`total = document.getElementById('purchases').innerHTML`, or move `var total = 0` outside of function.

Comment: I didn't think about moving the total outside the function LOL you're right. Thanks :)

Comment: You can mark answer as accepted if that solved your problem :).